error method not allowed This method is not allowed for the requested URL
I am writing python code using flask and html and I want to send an email to me via the site, an error appears that the method is not allowed code below
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import smtplib


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/order', methods=['POST'])
def process_order():
    def send_email():
        email = request.form['email']
        message = request.form['message']

        # Sending an email
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login("rprp9**@gmail.com", "***")
        server.sendmail("rprp9**7@gmail.com", email, message.encode('utf-8'))
        server.quit()

    return "The request has been sent successfully, you will be answered soon!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

order.html below:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/order" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I tried many ways from the Internet, nothing helped.

What url route is supposed to display the form, so the user can fill it out and submit it?

It sounds like you tried to load the /order route in your browser, but that would be a GET request, and you specifically coded that route to only accept POST requests.

In the "/order" route decorator add GET method as well: methods=["GET", "POST"]
Either way your current implementation does nothing but returns a string.
To actually call a function under process_order() you could use a package  like Flask WTF.
